# Retornar dados de uma tabela N:N apenas com chaves estrangeiras

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, sou inciante na linguagem SQL, e estou querendo saber como retornar os valores das chaves estrangeiras em uma relação N:N exemplo, retornar o nome do produto e o nome da peça. Grato desde já.

[image: tabelas]

Comment: Select p.nome_produto, pp.nome_peças from produto p
inner join lista_p lp on p.idProduto = lp.idProduto
inner join Peças pp on lp.idPeças = pp.idPeças

Comment: Obrigado Marconi, fiz algumas alterações e deu certo!! vlw =)

Comment: Bom que pude ajudar Deltman, bem vindo ao stackoverflow. É interessante dá uma lida no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funcionam as coisas por aqui. Recomendo a leitura nesse post: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join), irá te dá uma visão mais detalhada sobre consultas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, vou ler sim =).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você pode usar algo assim:

```
select lp.idProduto,  pd.nome_produto, lp.[idPeças] , pc.[nome_peça]
from [lista_peça] lp inner join produto pd on pd.idProduto = lp.idProduto
inner join [Peças] pc on pc.[idPeças] = lp.[idPeças]
```

Porém aconselho fortemente a não utilizar caracteres especiais nas tabelas e campos.

Abs.